# Mutex + Lock based on a line executing, but not necessarily finishing

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, mutex

I've got a block of code (Save) that can only executed by a single process at once and am successfully protecting it with a Mutex.

However, there is some cleanup (SavePrep) that also gets done inside of the protected block that can be long running and could be COPIED outside of the protected block.  The key is that it HAS to be run inside of the protected block, but if it is run outside of the protected block a bit before it's turn comes around it will decrease the amount of time spent in the protected block.  (Basically it has less prep work to do.)

Now the problem comes about because this SavePrep has a LOCK option to it.  I can run it outside of the protected block with lock set to FALSE and then the protected block can concurrently run SavePrep with LOCK set to TRUE without an issue.  However, the reversion isn't true, if it is being run with LOCK TRUE, then running with LOCK FALSE will fail.

So what I would like to do is prevent SavePrep inside the protected block from executing until after SavePrep has started outside of the protected block.

It is a single line of code that I'm calling in both cases. Is there anyway to block on the one line of code STARTING execution?

What I'm doing now is calling ReleaseMutex, then calling SavePrep.  However, I'm uncertain if the next process sitting at a WaitOne(..) will get given control before the SavePrep has a chance to start.

Sample of what it currently looks like with up to 20 or 30 processes waiting at times.

```
    Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, mutexName);  
    if (mutex.WaitOne(60 * 2 * 1000)  
    {  
        //Can take a while.  Can accept false to not lock if running outside of Wait  
        SavePrep(true);  
        Save();  
        mutex.ReleaseMutex();
    }
```

What I've don't but have concerns about a race condition with:

```
    Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, mutexName);  
    if (mutex.WaitOne(60 * 2 * 1000)  
    {  
        //Can take a while.  Can accept false to not lock if running outside of Wait  
        SavePrep(true);  
        Save();  
        mutex.ReleaseMutex();
    }  

    //Simplified.  There is a singleton I've used to keep up with who else is waiting 
    // on the mutex and the SavePrep is actually called with the necessary data for
    // a thread further back in the queue so that when it gets to SavePrep it takes
    // less time.
    //Is there anyway to guarantee this SavePrep call will execute before another
    // enters the WaitOne block?
    SavePrep(false);
```

Comment: This question is difficult to follow.  Consider writing a simplified short compileable example and pasting that code here to demostrate what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: If you're using a single process why do you need mutexes?

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear.  Surprisingly it is clearer than when I first wrote it up.  :)

Comment: @CookieOfFortune, there are multiple processes, is there something in my question that seems to suggest otherwise?  I'll try to clarify the question.

Comment: Okay, I think the code should help make the question a bit more understandable.

Comment: The code you posted is incomplete.  Questions:  Is the bottom segment of code a single method?  Does SavePrep belong to the same class as potential method?  The last comment does not make sense.  Where is this singleton? What does a singleton have to do with tracking threads?  This description is not a singleton.  For this question, please make an effort to post code that will compile.

Comment: I cannot post code that will compile as there are references to third party assemblies that you will not have and are not related to this problem.  This code was just to show some framework for the question.  You are correct, nothing in the code that I posted involves the singleton that I mentioned.  I only mentioned it because it is the mechanism that I am using to keep track of information about the processes that are waiting.  I don't think you need to know anything about the singleton for this question.

Comment: The second block of code shows the format for the changes I have made based on the description above.  It shows the SavePrep(true) and SavePrep(false) that I am worried about having a race condition for.